# rewrite url in htaccess file codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using codeigniter for development. I've used .htaccess file to shorten my URL i.e. to remove index.php from all URL's.
which is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have page in which I'm displaying user's portfolio through following link

www.example.com/users/username/id

Here 'users' is controller, 'username' is first parameter which is not unique and 'id' is second parameter which is unique so that i can display unique portfolio of user. It calls 'users' index function in which I pass this parameter.

Now, I want my URL to be like this 'www.example.com/username/id' by rewriting URL through .htaccess file.
When I try to do this, codeigniter considers 'username' as controller instead of parameter.

Is there any way to achieve this? If yes I'll appreciate your time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs it says you can just add a route so you can hide the users part:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['username/:num'] = "users/username/$1";
```

Now you can use the link to show the user (with specific id) like this:

```
<a href="username/$id">
```

Instead of `<a href="users/username/$id">`

for example

Hopefully it helps you :)

Comment: I used your reference and it helped me lot. Thank you